# How can i read the decimal character of my computer?

Tags: vb.net, internationalization

I would like to get the decimal character with vb.net
In Greek the decimal character is "," while in other countries they have "." as decimal character.

So how can i read, with .net what is the decimal character?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand what you're asking.  Do you want to write a program that can tell what the decimal point character is?  Do you want to know how to find out yourself?  Do you want to make sure your program reads the decimal point character properly?

Comment: Care to explain why this is needed? Are you printing or reading some number? You may not need to explicitly know what that character is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at these properties:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator
```